# Failed audit - reason 'primarily opinion-based' based

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I have [failed this audit today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794816/boxing-of-nsstring-stringwithformat-like-nsnumber), It was closed with a 'primarily opinion-based' reason. I am assuming this question was picked out accidentally by the system and is not a good audit question or should it have been closed and I am missing something?
To me it seems like a valid 'another way to do this' type of question.

It was a 'Vote to close' type of audit

Comment: 5 straight downvotes and the close votes were presumably unanimous, so yes, auto-picked.

Comment: The questioner themselves being the first one to vote to close may also have weighed a little.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would upvoting the question remove it from the audits? I'm no expert in objective-c but it doesn't look like an opinion based question to me either.

Comment: @JonK: I think a dissenting vote would indeed remove it from consideration from audits. I am just hesitant to do so here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know what you mean, I don't really want to upvote it either. Partly because it's way outside of my domain, and partly because I'm not sure that it's actually a good question. The only thing I'm sure about is that the given close reason is wrong...

Comment: Well, I did upvote it now. I don't think it's a very good question, but I do think it's not a *bad* question, and IMO it did not deserve even a single downvote, so I'm happy to help balance it somewhat.

Comment: @hvd as of now, that's the only way to [bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We want to have audits that are *rarely* of this type, where 'failing' simply indicates that you found yourself at odds with the consensus of folks that voted a certain way, *and not that you were simply not paying attention*. That's a very hard problem to solve, and no matter *how* smart we make it, there will always be an edge case where this happens.

I've said this many, many times before, but:

- If you were paying attention to what you were doing
- If you took the action that you honestly felt was the appropriate action to take
- And you subsequently 'failed' the audit

... ***don't worry about it, and just move on from there.***. There's no black mark against your record for this happening occasionally, there's positively nothing to worry about and you should *never* take feedback from a cognition-impaired robot *personally*.

Audits are *primarily* designed to catch people that are just trying to speed-click their way to a few badges. While they *do* have other benefits, such as helping new reviewers get up to speed with our quirks -  those are secondary benefits.

As it stands, we've 'bolted' a *considerable* amount of stuff onto review since it first debuted. I don't think we properly anticipated how *much* people would attempt to game the system in order to get badges, and that was, quite frankly, a bit disheartening. Consequently, audits were bolted on - and then stuff bolted onto audits, and then stuff bolted onto that.

As we continue diving into the quality project ([MSE summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project) | [MSO summary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project)), queues are going to get a lot of fundamental fixing that they've been longing for, which includes smarter audits. Every time you think contention is easy to catch, well, this happens :)

`tl;dr` - You weren't doing 180 in a 60 zone; ignore the automatic speeding ticket, but please do appreciate just how many *real* speeders it catches. And, don't forget - *any* time you feel strongly that the community made a wrong call, this is the place to go. The fact that it came up in an audit might be interesting, but could detract from the goal of actually getting people to reopen it.

Comment: I do not consider myself to be 'very good' reviewer TBH as I already had a ban and this is my problem - I can't be certain that I am not the one who is failing as sometimes it can tricky to tell which way it is, or when I get 4 close votes and I think it's the other way it's hard not to go with the flow (I usually skip questionable reviews nowdays). Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: @LIUFA You probably just find yourself at odds with how other folks voted. That _probably_ means chiming into discussions about governance and such would be a great thing for you to do. If you're ever unsure, if the waters look even a little muddy, just skip. You're not a bad reviewer, you put your full attention into it, our quirks just make it interesting. One should always take a moment to reflect upon one's quirks, after all :)

Comment: @LIUFA knowing when to think "I'm not sure what to do here and should skip instead of guessing" is an important part of effective reviewing.  I do wish in those cases there was a better way to see what the consensus of other reviewers was than leaving the question open in a tab for a few hours/days to see what happens to it.

Comment: @TimPost: skipping seems to have the problem that when you hit many audits with that, you dont build up a "many audits passed" record and are more likely to get a ban.

Comment: "I don't think we properly anticipated how much people would attempt to game the system in order to get badges" So abolish badges then.  They are a fundamental silly idea... does anyone who usefully contributes really care about them?

Comment: @ChrisStratton would enough people still do some of the boring tasks where a badge is the only reward?  I'd be curious to see how many people slow down or stop reviewing shortly after getting gold badges and what fraction of the total reviews are from people who appear to be just badge collectors?  I suspect the answer is a lot of them and enough that most of the queues would end up looking like the close vote queue does today.

Comment: I'd personally much rather see those queues abolished as well, and voting on questions handled by those **with enough interest in the topics** to read the questions on their merits.  We get much better decisions made when they are made *by people who could potentially answer the question*.

Comment: @PlasmaHH if one focuses on clear cut cases, skipping still allows to build an "audit weight". I know that because that's exactly what happens to me in CV queue: I likely skip over lots of "known good" audits, but I am getting (and effortlessly passing) a decent amount of "known bad" ones