# Should we have new reviewers go through a series of Audits before starting "live" reviews?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits

With the slew of recent Hot Meta Topics such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266964/failed-audit-reason-primarily-opinion-based-based?cb=1), and many others like it, does anyone else feel like it might be a benefit to have people go through a series of 5-10 audit questions before they're allowed to review actual review questions?

There could even be a little Q/A thing that could auto generate Meta questions if they have any concerns as to the results they got during their "training".

I'm not at all suggesting we get rid of the random audits throughout the review process, but I think this would greatly help reduce the number of people failing random audits and getting temp bans from reviewing just because they didn't know the guidelines when they first started reviewing.

I know I had some problems with that early on, and after those first few audit fails, THEN I was able to understand more of why my approach was different from the community.

Comment: My feature request could double up to provide this functionality: [The Good, The Bad & The Ugly Tutorial](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly), with dummy reviews to allow users to practice and learn the difference between good & bad posts.

Comment: I agree to some extent, @Tanner. However, I'm part of the consensus there about adding the additional  information/guidance before asking a question won't be met with the best response. However, when it comes to reviews, there's literally nothing there to help you know, and a lot of people aren't in line with the community mindset.

Comment: There are suggestions in comments that users could do the tutorial at any time as well as when they first sign up, which would make it useful to your suggestion. I think in the whole though, users would learn from it and not get the usual backlash from established users when they ask low quality questions, which is a common first experience on SO.

Comment: Similar discussion on Meta.SE: ["Give new edit reviewers some audits to begin with"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214541/give-new-edit-reviewers-some-audits-to-begin-with)

Comment: Yes, as long as the audits are harder. Audits now just show make sure you're paying attention, they don't verify that you know how to review or anything fancy.