# How is an unclear question with an error message dump as a title and no details, a good review audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was presented with the following:

[image]

Problems with question:

- Problem was with upgrading an IDE, nothing to do with code
- Seems quite broad/unclear without additional info on the project
- Seems quite broad/unclear without providing the steps taken to upgrade the IDE
- No debugging or trace done/provided to solve the problem

This question is clearly **unclear what you're asking**:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Questions:

- This question was revealed to have **8**!!! upvotes after I failed the audit. **Why do we use poorly asked questions with high upvotes for an audit?**
- Why display misleading vote count on audits at all? Shouldn't we also consider the votes (not just content) on the question to decide whether to keep it open?

Link to disputed review audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5422019

Comment: it's good that it was chosen as an audit because now meta effect will kick in and the question will get downvoted, closed and removed. If it got you review banned then I am sure a mod will remove such ban.

Comment: Problems with the IDE are on topic. "software tools commonly used by programmers;". That said, it does lack detail making it quite broad

Comment: Closing this would be unproductive. The thing you have to realize about an issue with a tool is that one often does not have ready access to the same kind of debug information as is available when ones own code fails; yet the problem is every bit as serious and relevant to software development, **and even more likely to benefit from community knowledge** than a problem in ones own code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It had quite a few votes, *answers* with quite a few votes, a decent vote velocity and *zero* flags. To an algorithm, *that looks like a great audit*.

I've gone into this more in depth in my [answer the last time this happened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266964/failed-audit-reason-primarily-opinion-based-based/267077#267077). ***We can not hope to make these perfect as long as decisions that human beings make drive them.*** At least, not with our current system.

The new quality stuff that is being tested will be *much* better at ejecting things like this from audits; or rather, passing and showing one scores say is more clear-cut. Titles like that make turtles cry and that *is* something we should be able to pick up on.

But, no system is perfect. So the *final* thing I'm going to say on these is:

1. ***We know this happens, and have explained why dozens of times.***
2. ***We hope to deploy a system where this happens far less frequently soon.***
3. ***No system is perfect, this will always happen, but happen to a far lesser extent.***

They (audits) were necessary because some folks can't be trusted to come by badges honestly. Once we have a *much* more precise *set* of calculated scores for posts, we can be *much* smarter about how we slow that particular variety of reviewer down.

Until then, bear with us, shrug it off and know we're actively trying to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for doing a great job Tim! I understand no system is perfect :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong though, but bringing these types of situations to light is still a positive thing as it helps debug the system that picks what items are for review (and the upcoming new system). So you are only saying to bear with the system and not get bent out of shape over failing an audit, but letting the community know is still appreciated?

Comment: @krillgar I believe what Tim is saying is that such occurences are brought here every other day or so, and that flagging every single one of them won't make things go smoother. From what he posted, I understand they are working on the audit process and the filters in the review queue, and until these changes become public, we'll have to live with the current system.

Comment: I agree. The way it was worded I wasn't sure if the influx of "hey this audit I failed was wrong because of X, Y, and Z" with 15 people upvoting them was helpful or not. I'm not saying anything about the way the current system works, but as we're all programmers, we (should) all know the benefit of detailed end-user feedback about abnormalities in our algorithms.