# Is that question on topic at all?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I've just failed an audit on that question: [Remove Achievement from iTunes Connect Game Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671168/remove-achievement-from-itunes-connect-game-center)

Maybe I don't get something, but I can't see how it should be on topic. It's not about the programming, it's about using someone's else web interface.

Is such question on topic on SO?

Comment: From what I understand, the question is about managing achievements for a game OP developed. Looks fine to me.

Comment: Looks off-topic to me. It's not about programming or tools used in programming. It's belongs on Apple's support center.

Comment: OTOH you could make a case for it being a tool used primarily by programmers.

Comment: just [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773). That said, "known good" audits appear unusually slippery today: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24626050) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24669350/839601) made me raise eyebrows. I even recognized first one by filter mismatch but failed because I thought it's "known bad", it was so much worse that any known good audit I saw before, go figure :)

Comment: @gnat I'm glad I skipped the second one today. I'm still trying to find my way about the site policies. I failed yesterday on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631744/any-equivalent-gulp-plugin-for-doing-grunt-bower). It seemed to me off-topic *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow ...*

Comment: @VMai audit you refer looks faulty to me. As for site policies, [current official stance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267077/839601 "here") appears to be that responsible reviewer shouldn't worry about infrequent failures. I am somewhat concerned though that audit selection algorithm seems to be changed recently, so that even attentive reviewers may start failing frequently

Comment: There are faulty audits? Good to know ... recently I've had two or three audits I failed where I couldn't figure out why ...

Comment: @Infinite - I agree with the poster that its a poor review question. However, the rule you cite makes it on topic. iTunes is a tool used by programmers to transfer programs to their devices. I despise the f**king rule because it brings in so much spurious junk that Stack Overflow should merge with Super User. Also see [Please add verbiage in Help Center to reflect policy on site/server configurations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262917/please-add-verbiage-in-help-center-to-reflect-policy-on-site-server-configuratio).

Comment: @jww: Rules say SO is for tools used **in** programming, not tools used **by** programmers. The question is closed now, you can refer the language on the close reason box :)

Comment: @Infinite - check the language used in the [Help Center's](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ***What topics can I ask about here?***. Its defiently ***by programmers***. Like I said, its *worthless* criteria.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope. It was a bad audit.

It's closed now.

Comment: it is only one vote shy of being re-opened!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Huh? It says 2 votes for me, and since there's nothing in the queue I think it received Leave Closed reviews to move it out.

Comment: It's open again.