# Wording in close reasons and help center makes it unclear what belongs on SO v. SU

Tags: discussion

I continue to see questions closed as "general computing hardware and software". For example, [Remove Achievement from iTunes Connect Game Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671168/remove-achievement-from-itunes-connect-game-center). Then, a Meta debate sometimes occurs. For example, [Is that question on topic at all?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267995/is-that-question-on-topic-at-all).

There's no explanation for "general computing hardware and software ... Super User" other than the close reason itself. See [List of close reasons for Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68876/list-of-close-reasons-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Unfortunately, the Stack Overflow policy of ["tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (quote from the Help Center's ***What topics can I ask about here?***) means nearly every package, program and command is on-topic. It contradicts the Super User close reason, and its a worthless criteria.

Past requests to improve or revise the statement have been unsuccessful. For example, [Please add verbiage in Help Center to reflect policy on site/server configurations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262917/please-add-verbiage-in-help-center-to-reflect-policy-on-site-server-configuratio).

Please remove the Super User close reasons and merge with Super User. Under a merged site, nearly all questions that programmers have can be asked and answered under the site's policy.

Comment: I don't see the contradiction. If it is about *general computing hardware and software* it should be asked on Super User. If it is about programming, or about a tool used by programmers, then it should be on Stack Overflow. Not all tools are primarily used by programmers.

Comment: Do you actually think SO should be merged with SU or is that just click bait? Do you just want close reasons / help center copy improved?

Comment: @user000001 - Where are you getting the word ***primarily***? Is that your interpretation? Because its clearly not the language used in the Help Center.

Comment: @djechlin - no, I don't believe that. I want to bring attention [again] to that piss poor wording that causes endless confusion and debate. I knew the question was going to be murdered in the polls.

Comment: @jww so it's just click bait. Can you please write a more accurate and mature title for your question?

Comment: @jww when you say "again" do you mean this is a duplicate? would you mind posting the link so we can close it?

Comment: @jww So your interpretation of "tools commonly used by programmers" could include a web browser, MS word, or any other program that *could* be used by a programmer? I don't think that that is the intent, and I surely don't interpret it like that...

Comment: @djechlin - past attempts to bring attention to the issue and get the wording change failed. This is a new suggestion since past suggestions were dismissed. I'm not sure your edits were appropriate. As for click bait, we need catchy titles to get folks interested and onboard. For example, the American people bought the PATRIOT Act hook, line and sinker even though it was a page out of Nazi Germany. Catchy titles work wonders.

Comment: Thanks for asking a new question [instead of comments on my old comment.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267995/is-that-question-on-topic-at-all?noredirect=1#comment75378_267995)

Comment: @jww: Am not offended at all, am relieved :) An open discussion with community is a very good way to address the issue. I wouldn't have been able to comment on it.

Comment: Except SE is well regulated enough that we can prohibit blatant attempts at inaccurate propagandizing. Unless you're really arguing, "We should be run MORE like Congress." If you "didn't get enough attention" maybe you were wrong or your issue was unimportant.

Comment: @Infinite - sorry about that. I did not parse that correctly. I deleted the comment.

Comment: @djechlin - continuing confusion and endless debate over *"tools commonly used by programmers"* would seem to indicate otherwise. I think it highlights the unwillingness of the site to fix the core problem.

Comment: `For example, the American people bought the PATRIOT Act hook, line and sinker even though it was a page out of Nazi Germany. Catchy titles work wonders.` Oh, that analogy will help keep this discussion civil...

Comment: @jww Your analogy is actually reversed, since you gave the question a title (and thesis statement) people *wouldn't* like in order to draw attention. An equivalent would be if politicians named their bill the "Kill the Orphans Act" to "bring attention" to another issue. You could also call it clickbait, or simply trolling.

Answer (score 15):

Merging with Super User (or any other site) would be a bad thing.

I think you are misinterpreting the "tools commonly used by programmers" clause. This is there to allow questions about:

- Source control
- Development environments
- etc.

While these questions *could* be on topic over on Super User they're more likely to get a better answer on Stack Overflow.

What this clause doesn't cover is questions about:

- Microsoft Office products
- iTunes
- Photoshop
- etc.

These are all things used by the general public and not **specifically** software developers. You are likely to get a worse answer for a question on these topics on Stack Overflow as developers are not generally experts in these products.

Having said all that, the question you mention about the iTunes Connect Game Center [sic] probably is on topic on Stack Overflow as it's a question about a developer centric part of the site. Had you made your question just about getting this question reopened it would have fared better than this one.

Comment: *"Had you made your question just about getting this question reopened it would have fared better than this one"* - no interest in that. I knew this question was going to be beat to hell. I wanted to bring attention [again] to the ***poor*** wording in the Help Center.

Comment: *"I think you are misinterpreting the "tools commonly used by programmers" clause."* - I believe I understand the intent. Unfortunately, many other disagree and they cite that exact rule. The rule is worded poorly, and its hard to argue against it because its so broad.

Comment: @jww It might be constructive to suggest a better wording (I'm not sure I can think of one). I don't think it's productive to say "Since some people are misled by one sentence in the Help Center, we should merge together the two biggest sites on the network."

Comment: @David - I agree. If the site was going to move on a wording change to make it more clear, then they would have done it by now. Since the site does not appear to want to change the wording, this suggestion was another way to skin the cat. They can keep the wording the same, and move all the on-topic content in one place.

Comment: @jww: a) You still haven't suggested an example of a *better* wording. Why do you assume one exists? Why do you assume that if you suggested a better wording that your suggestion wouldn't be accepted and implemented? b) Merging the two sites would have a substantial effect on literally millions of users and millions of existing questions. This would be in order to solve the problem of a small handful of confused Meta questions.